# S3 multipart upload, "ETag" vs "Etag"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm doing multipart S3 uploads, which seem to be working except for an unexpected letter case change in the response headers. I'm getting "Etag" instead of [the documented "ETag"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html) . It seems like a minor detail but my header lookups are case sensitive-- so I don't want to assume that the lower case "t" is something I can expect to be unchanged. I could do a case-insensitive header lookup but that seems like papering over the difference, and I prefer to understand what I'm doing whenever possible.

Comment: RFC7230 states that headers are case insensitive, so it shouldn't matter: "Each header field consists of a case-insensitive field name followed
   by a colon (":"), optional leading whitespace, the field value, and
   optional trailing whitespace."

Comment: @IgorPantović thanks, that's very interesting. I'm working in iOS and this suggests that the built-in networking framework may have a bug related to this.

Comment: Also @IgorPantović if you make that an answer, I'll accept it, because it overrides any concerns about what Amazon's doing.

Comment: Felt like it wasn't sufficient enough for an answer, but if it answers your question it's good enough I guess :)

Comment: It was exactly what I needed to know, even though I didn't realize that when I wrote the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFC7230 states that headers are case insensitive, so it shouldn't matter.
From [Section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2):

> Each header field consists of a case-insensitive field name followed
> by a colon (":"), optional leading whitespace, the field value, and
> optional trailing whitespace.

It is probably a good idea to normalize headers to lower/uppercase before doing a lookup.